# How to block tracee catch SIGTRAP with ptrace

Tags: c, linux, signals, ptrace

When I want to inspect tracee syscall I use `PTRACE_ATTACH` , then `PTRACE_SYSCALL` in loop , and finally `PTRACE_DETACH` .

The problem is that if the tracee registered to SIGTRAP or SIGCONT it can change his behaviour while I use PTRACE_SYSCALL or PTRACE_DETACH and I don't want to do it.

When I attach to tracee with `PTRACE_ATTACH` tracee got `SIGSTOP` but it can't register/reaction to this signal, so that it fine.

What is the solution that the tracee could not catch SIGTRAP when I use `PTRACE_SYSCALL` or SIGCONT when I used `PTRACE_CONT`

Comment: See my recent comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667231/how-to-prevent-another-process-to-debug-syscall-with-ptrace?noredirect=1#comment109082322_61667231

Comment: @CraigEstey That actually sounds like the exact opposite of this. In that question, the asker was playing the role of malware author, and wanted to know how to keep security researchers from using `ptrace` to analyze their malware. In this question, the asker is playing the role of security researcher, and wants to know how to use `ptrace` to analyze (presumably with breakpoints) malware.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica The techniques for preventing tracee from doing anything that tracer doesn't want are the same. If you start from `PTRACE_TRACEME`, tracer can modify/supress any tracee syscall that it wants _before_ it happens. If from `PTRACE_ATTACH`, tracer may have to inject code to _undo_ something tracee has already done (e.g. `signal(SIGTRAP,SIG_IGN)`).

Comment: @Catig , how does the tracer can `undo` `signal(SIGTRAP,...)` for example if the tracee registered to this signal before the tracer attach to tracee?

Comment: @Keystone The point of suppressing the signal is that you can keep their signal handler from running without having to unset it.

Answer (score 1):

The tracer always gets first dibs at signal handling, and it can choose to suppress the signal so that the tracee's handler doesn't run. The only thing you have to worry about is if the tracee blocks the signal with something like `sigprocmask` or a blocking call to `pselect` and uses something like `sigpending` or `signalfd` to look for it, which you could fix by modifying or emulating the relevant syscalls.

To suppress a signal, just pass 0 for `sig` when resuming after signal-delivery-stop. From [`man 2 ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

> ## Signal injection and suppression
>
> After signal-delivery-stop is observed by the tracer, the tracer should restart the tracee with the call
>
> ```
> ptrace(PTRACE_restart, pid, 0, sig)
> ```
>
> where `PTRACE_restart` is one of the restarting ptrace requests.  If `sig` is 0, then a signal is not delivered.  Otherwise, the signal `sig` is delivered.  This operation is called *signal injection* in this manual page, to distinguish it from signal-delivery-stop.